# Which of these insertion sorts is better?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

1. Sedgewicks Insertion Sort (Java):

   ```
       int N = a.length; 
       for (int i = 1; i < N; i++){
            for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j],a[j-1]); j--)
                  exchange(a, j, j-1);
            }
       }
   ```

Or this one (the difference is in the exchange part, Sedgewick exchanges [j] with [j-1] each iteration, whereas the following saves the moved value to a temp, moves [j-1] to [j] on each iteration and after it exits the inner loop, then it places the original value stored in temp, to its final position [j]):

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
      int j = i;
      int temp = arr[j];
      while(j >= 1 && temp < arr[j-1]){
           arr[j] = arr[j-1];
           j--;
      }
      arr[j] = temp;
 }
```

Is there any substantial difference? Are they roughly the same? Am I overthinking to much?

Comment: Insertion sort isn’t good except for learning algorithms. So I guess the “better” one is the one that students understand more easily.

Comment: I wouldn't say that insertion sort isn't good. It depends on the data set and conditions where your algorithm will run.

Comment: Interesting, @Vusal. Which is a situation where for production code insertion sort is preferable over Java’s built-in sort methods using the TimSort algorithm?

Comment: If the size of the input is small enough and for example you don't have sufficient memory - it might make a sense to use insertion sort. More you can read her: https://www.cse.unr.edu/~chen_q/sorta.html

Comment: @Vusal Does TimSort take up extra space? Even if it did, if the input is small, then the extra space required for TimSort would be *very* small. I still can’t imagine a situation where the cost of writing and maintaining your own sort code is worth that little bit of space. I would even suggest that the extra code may take up more space.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it uses a stack to collect "runs" and then merges them, so it does use extra space. It's not about the space only, and by the way, TimSort also uses insertion sort in some cases, if the size of the run is below some threshold. And I'm not saying that one must implement any sorting algorithm, unless there is no way around (we always must try to use already tested libraries). I'm just saying that Insertion sort algorithm is not useless and is not for educational purposes only. The fact that it's not useless doesn't mean that you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Imagine you have an embedded hardware you need to program, and you have very little memory there, you don't have a luxury of including some libraries (not much memory), and you have to sort some array of data. I personally would write an insertion sort algorithm in that case, because it's very simple, easy to write and debug. And it's much easier to read than others.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any substantial difference? Are they roughly the same? Am I overthinking to much?

They seem to both have a nested loop and consequently `O(n^2)` runtime complexity. They are roughly the same. The differences are so minor, nobody cares about them in practice.

If you want to gain an understanding about what matters for sorting problems and why and be able to compare them you can look into this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-different-sorting-techniques/)

In reality, what matters for a sorting algorithm is its asymptotic runtime complexity, which is called `Big-O` and denoted like this `O(f(x))`.

It shows how fast/slow the algorithm is for BIG inputs. Nobody cares about small inputs, because for them **every** algorithm is fast.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely observational perspective, they are equivalent.

- for sorted lists in ascending order, they each perform `0` swaps.
- for completely reversed lists, sorting in ascending order they perform the same number of swaps. For `N` items this would be `N*(N-1)/2` and is the maximum possible, given the loop parameters sans any item comparisons.
- for repeated sorting of randomly generated values they both perform the same number of swaps.

Answer (score 0):

The practical considerations are subtle.
If this is the first time the programmer interacts with insertion sort, perhaps they are not important.
However, for a library implementation of the sorting, they are significant.
Why library at all: because it has good speed for small arrays, so, many library-grade sorting routines use insertion sort when the part of the array to sort becomes small enough ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort#Implementations)).

So, here are a couple of subtle differences.

1. Consider sorting an array of objects where comparison is cheap but moving and copying are expensive. For (a non-Java-specific) example, the array may store bulky structs instead of pointers to them. Then the first version is slower by a constant factor: for example, while element 10 goes to position 0, the first version performs 10 swaps (20 to 30 assignments), whereas the second one does the thing in 11 assignments.
2. Consider having non-copyable objects (for example, `unique_ptr` in C++). Then we should only swap the elements and never duplicate or overwrite. The first version just works, and the second version requires additional tweaks: create a dummy element for `temp` to have something to swap with.